# How do we debug Maui applications that work in the debugger, but crash on the device?

Tags: debugging, azure-application-insights, maui

I'm stuck. I've got an application that works in Windows, it works on the iOS simulators, but it crashes when I deliver it through Ad Hoc or the AppStore.

I tried to install Application Insights. This works in Windows mode, but doesn't work on the iOS simulated devices.

How do we debug a MAUI application when it runs in debug, but fails on the device?

Comment: Have you tried deploying directly to the device from VS?  Do you have any crash reporting tools?  Is it crashing after launch or during?

Comment: @Jason - 'Do you have any crash reporting tools' That's what I'm asking. What tools are available for MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I had same problem with my application. It turned out that there was error in the xaml file which was untraceable. that doesn't throw any error in the debug mode. Application runs successfully. I wrote nothing in the constructor of a page, yet opening the page was crashing the application. So I had to be sure that there is something in the UI itself.

I re scanned the xaml file and removed all recently added codes. One was CommunicationToolkit.Maui. After removing it from many lines, it loaded the page successfully atleast. Then I with much caution started readding those toolkit lines one by one and finally arrived at the erroneous line. It was a picker where the toolkit seems to not work. So that's it. Good luck, Happy hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding Microsoft App Center?

Comment: Yes. It's crap. Couldn't get it working. Have you used it?

Comment: I struggled to get it working, especially with .net 7, but eventually I managed. It seems to be catching errors quite nicely, along with stack trace after having uploaded symbols. Hopefully I'll get time to make a short video about it soon.